# Why does my php drop down form result in an Undefined offset

Tags: php, forms

Please could you check this code and see why its returning an Undefined offset: and how it can be fixed.

options.php

```
<?php
$options = array();
$options["PC 1"] = array("year"=>"2000","colour"=>"blue");
$options["PC 2"] = array("year"=>"2003","colour"=>"pink");
$options["PC 3"] = array("year"=>"2006","colour"=>"orange"); 
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="input" action="test.php" method="post">
Device Name: <?php
include("options.php");
echo '<select name="option">';
foreach($options as $name => $values)
{    echo '<option value="' .$name .'">' .$name .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php
include("options.php");
$chosenValue = $_POST['option'];
list($year,$colour) = $options[$chosenValue];  ---- here is the error line

echo $year;
echo $colour;

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error? As in "Notice: Undefined offset 'offset' on Line 8'

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\wol\test.php on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think it's because the key's in your array `$options` have spaces in them. Which is completely valid/legal in PHP, but in HTML, when the form is submitted it doesn't like it.</s>

Try changing them to `$options["PC1"]` and so on and see if it fixes it.

**Edit**: From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) - `list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.`

Try changing `test.php` to:

```
<?php
include("options.php");
$chosenValue = $_POST['option'];
$year = $options[$chosenValue]['year'];
$colour = $options[$chosenValue]['colour'];

echo $year;
echo $colour;
?>
```

Comment: Edit'd my post with a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you access year and colour in `test.php`, `list()` doesn't seem to work well with non-numeric indices. One of the user-contributed comments in the php docs suits your needs

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php#53420

Or just go for

```
$data = &$options[$chosenValue];
echo $data['year']; // etc
```